# Why it is showing only one box in export of processing.org java pdf?

Tags: java, processing, p5.js

Here is my code down below, when in run it shows multiple boxes as I wanted but when I try to export, it only shows a single box at that frame position.I tried generating output at particular frame but its same issue

```
import processing.pdf.*;
int ofs = 500;


boolean record;

void setup() {
  size(1900, 1080, P3D);
}

void draw() {
  if (record) {
    beginRaw(PDF, "box.pdf");
  }


  background(255);
  translate(width/2, height/2, -800);
  
  rotateZ(0.3);
  rotateY(frameCount/500.0);
  float x = sin(radians(frameCount*0.1));
   for ( int xo = -ofs; xo<=ofs; xo += 100) {
     for ( int yo = -ofs; yo<=ofs; yo += 100) {
        pushMatrix();
        translate ( xo, yo, 0);
        box(200*x);
        fill(155,150,90);
        strokeWeight(3*x);
        popMatrix();
  if (record) {
    endRaw();
    record = false;
  }
    }
      }
        }

void keyPressed() {
  if (key == 'r') {
    record = true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So close! :)

Perhaps the formatting might have made it harder to spot the issue.
You're calling `endRaw();` (which wraps up pdf recording) nested in the `for` loops.

This means it's only picking up the first box since `record` is set to `false` so the other boxes are ignored.

I recommend using **Edit > Auto Format** (CMD + T / Ctrl + T).

Simply move the `if(record)` after the nested `for` loops:

```java
import processing.pdf.*;
int ofs = 500;


boolean record;

void setup() {
  size(1400, 580, P3D);
}

void draw() {
  if (record) {
    beginRaw(PDF, "box.pdf");
  }


  background(255);
  translate(width/2, height/2, -800);

  rotateZ(0.3);
  rotateY(frameCount/500.0);
  float x = sin(radians(frameCount*0.1));
  for ( int xo = -ofs; xo<=ofs; xo += 100) {
    for ( int yo = -ofs; yo<=ofs; yo += 100) {
      pushMatrix();
      translate ( xo, yo, 0);
      box(200*x);
      fill(155, 150, 90);
      strokeWeight(3*x);
      popMatrix();
    }
  }
  
  // finish recording to PDF only after everything was drawn 
  if (record) {
    endRaw();
    record = false;
  }
}

void keyPressed() {
  if (key == 'r') {
    record = true;
  }
}
```