# Processing 4.0, not being able to move my drawing

Tags: canvas, processing

The mouse should be roughly centered on the person's face. When the mouse is moved, the person moves along with it. You should use the mouseX and mouseY variables to determine where the mouse is. Also, you’ll need to use the setup() and draw() function for this one.

The person must have each of the following:
a face (ellipse)
eyes (ellipses)
mouth (triangle)
torso / legs (custom shape)
arms (rect)
hands (rect, triangle, ellipse, or custom)
feet (rect, triangle, ellipse, or custom)
hair (lines)
you will write a processing program that generates a drawing of person. This person will “follow” wherever the mouse moves along the screen. Below is an example animation of this happening in action:

[This is what its supposed to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mV46s.png)   [this is my code right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0KgL.png)

not able to move the image with my mouse, someone help me out.

Comment: https://postimg.cc/ZBX2vKsd (this is what my canvas looks like right now)

Comment: You should ost your code attempt. Check out the [2D Transformations Tutorial](https://processing.org/tutorials/transform2d) (`pushMatrix();translate(mouseX, mouseY);drawYourPerson();popMatrix();` should do the trick)

Comment: I did its up in the post, I got the drawing done but I cant get it to move with my mouse.

Comment: You posted picture of the drawing. To clarify, I meant a formatted code snippet. This makes it easy for other to read the code and ideally run it. The easier you make it for everyone, the more likely you'll be to get accurate answers. Here's an [example of a recent question with code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73634805/why-it-is-showing-only-one-box-in-export-of-processing-org-java-pdf). In terms of code formatting you can find an [exhaustive answer here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks). Welcome to stackoverflow :)

Comment: @RomeluLuke I spotted the code you posted as an image (which [you should avoid](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question#:~:text=You%20should%20not%20post%20code,order%20to%20reproduce%20the%20problem.)). Re-reading your question: it sounds like your asking people to help with your course assignment. The solution is in your question: you must use `setup()` and `draw()`. (`setup()` runs once: use `size()` here, `draw()` runs continously: add your code from `background()` onwards.) ...

Comment: ...Without `draw()` your sketch simply renders a single frame which is why you can't move the drawing. For more info see [Setup and Draw](https://processing.org/examples/setupdraw.html) and [Hello Processing](https://hello.processing.org/).